# Join ID names of one MySQL table to IDs in another

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have one table of client details identified by an ID that looks like this:

```
ID (the clientcode), Name, Details
```

I would like to reference the ID from another table with sales information and pick up the name of the client in the query.

My original query string that picked up just the ID (clientcode) is this:

```
SELECT clientcode, SUM(sales) FROM inventory WHERE manufacturer='1' 
  GROUP BY client code ORDER BY SUM(sales) DESC
```

I would like to also pick up the Name of the client referenced by clientcode.

I tried a few LEFT JOINs but couldn't get the queries working.

Comment: show us what didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT i.clientcode
     , c.name
     , SUM(i.sales)
  FROM inventory i
  LEFT
  JOIN clientdetails c
    ON c.id = i.clientcode
 WHERE i.manufacturer='1' 
 GROUP BY i.clientcode, c.name
 ORDER BY SUM(i.sales) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
SELECT c.ID, c.name, SUM(i.sales) 
FROM inventory i
JOIN clients c ON c.ID = i.clientcode
WHERE i.manufacturer='1' 
GROUP BY c.ID, ORDER BY SUM(i.sales) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple query to achieve this is:

```
SELECT i.clientcode, d.name, SUM(i.sales) FROM inventory i, details d
WHERE i.manufacturer='1'
  AND d.clientcode = i.clientcode
GROUP BY i.clientcode ORDER BY SUM(i.sales) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, try thisone out.

```
SELECT  inventory.clientcode, 
        SUM(inventory.sales),
        clientdetails.Name
FROM inventory 
        INNER JOIN clientdetails
            ON inventory.clientcode = clientdetails.clientcode
WHERE inventory.manufacturer='1' 
GROUP BY inventory.clientcode, clientdetails.Name
ORDER BY SUM(inventory.sales) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.clientcode, 
        SUM(a.sales),
        b.Name
FROM inventory a
        INNER JOIN clientdetails b
            ON a.clientcode = b.clientcode
WHERE a.manufacturer='1' 
GROUP BY a.clientcode, b.Name
ORDER BY SUM(a.sales) DESC
```